cvxpy - cp.Minimize giving no answer
I'm trying to get the expected returns that satisfies a set of known weights, asset covariance, a set of weight limits and an estimated risk aversion. I'm using cp.Minimize to solve the problem. But it's not working for me.
Essentially I'm trying to rewrite this code, where I use cp.Maximize to find expected returns:
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
import pandas as pd

def optimize_weights(expected_returns, asset_covariance, weight_limits, risk_aversion):
    n_assets = len(expected_returns)

    # Define variables
    x = cp.Variable(n_assets)

    # Objective function (maximize expected return - risk aversion * portfolio variance)
    objective = cp.Maximize(expected_returns @ x - risk_aversion * cp.quad_form(x, asset_covariance))

    # Constraints
    constraints = [
        x >= 0, # No short selling
        cp.sum(x) == 1, # Fully invested
    ]

    # Convert range constraints to individual constraints
    for i in range(n_assets):
        constraints.append(x[i] >= weight_limits[i][0] / 100)
        constraints.append(x[i] <= weight_limits[i][1] / 100)

    # Formulate and solve the problem
    problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
    problem.solve()

    # Extract optimized weights & round weights
    optimized_weights = np.round(x.value,4)

    return optimized_weights

But this time I pass it weights instead of expected returns and receive expected returns back as the output using cp.Minimize. Here is the example of what I've written.
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
import pandas as pd


    def reverse_optimze_expected_return(weights, asset_covariance, weight_limits, risk_aversion):
        
        n_assets = len(weights)
        
        expected_return = cp.Variable(n_assets)
        
        objective = cp.Minimize(cp.quad_form(weights, asset_covariance))
        
        constraints = [
            cp.sum(weights) == 1,
            cp.quad_form(weights, asset_covariance) <= risk_aversion,
            ]
        
        for i in range(n_assets):
            constraints.append(weights[i] >= weight_limits[i][0] / 100)
            constraints.append(weights[i] <= weight_limits[i][1] / 100)
            
        problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
        problem.solve()
        
        optimize_expected_returns = expected_return.value
        
        return optimize_expected_returns

data = {'Equity':[0.006385,-0.000215,0.000000], 'Bonds': [-0.000215, 0.000834, 0.000000], 'Cash':[0.000000,0.000000,0.000000] }
    
S = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
S = S.set_index(S.columns)
    
asset_covariance = S
    
weight_limits = [(42.5, 67.5), (32.5, 57.5), (0, 25)]
    
weights = np.array([0.55, 0.45, 0])
    
risk_aversion = 3.1880326818259768

reverse_optimze_expected_return(weights, asset_covariance, weight_limits, risk_aversion)

Where am I going wrong? Output I receive below:


"But it's not working for me." is not a sufficient description of the issue. Please attach log outputs, or error messages and fully reproducible code - nobody is going to copy data from the post to recreate the issue.

I've updated it now with all the code plus the error message.

You defined a variable expected_return but you are not using it anywhere in the code. In fact all your cvxpy model operates just on your constant input data, so you are adding constraints such as 100<=103, or similar. They all evaluate to Bool.

Yes you are right. I added more code for context. I should have done this to begin with. I'm trying to rewrite a function to give me expected returns which originally gave me weights.
